OpenLdap configuration for accessing multiple authorisation stores

I have the following scenario and I would like some hints on if feasible and how I could implement it. I consider myself inexperienced with OpenLdap proxying (not with Ldap in general); even though I have tried to implement the scenario with various overlays (meta, ldap, dynslist, rwm), I had no success.
This is my setup:

I have two ADs as upstream servers and I can bind (ldapsearch) successfully as either user of the AD1 or user of AD2 in order to list entries from both AD1 and AD2.
AD1 and AD2 do not share any common users (same sAMAccountName)
The same application groups (under a different base DN) exist both in AD1 and AD2, ie cn=read,ou=groups,dc=dom1,dc=com and cn=read,ou=groups,dc=dom2,dc=com a.o.
Users of AD1 can be associated with cn=read,ou=groups,dc=dom1,dc=com or other groups found in AD1 and users of AD2 with the respective group found in AD or for other groups.
The Ldap application will be configured with the URL of the OpenLdap proxy and the base DN is configurable as well.

What I would like to achieve by this query for example, would be the retrieval of the Ldif contents of the user account - independent of if the users and his group assignments are found in AD1 or AD2.
(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(sAMAccountName=myusername)
  (memberof=CN=mygroup,DC=unified,DC=com))

Note here, that the DC=unified,DC=com base DN of the proxy is used ie the query must be executed by both AD servers.
Is this possible? Any ideas or hints would be very helpful

What configurations have you tried? The 'meta' backend seems like it is specifically meant for this purpose, although slapd-meta(5) isn't very clear about how it handles search results.
